# How to find the MAXSIZE for user databases from a connection to master in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, dmv

While it is simple enough to SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@DatabaseName, 'MaxSizeInBytes') when connected to a user database, I have been unable to find how to get this information for all of the databases when connected to **master**.

I want to complete this query:

```
SELECT  Name                =   d.name
        ,Edition            =   sdo.edition
        ,ServiceObjective   =   sdo.service_objective
        ,CurrentMaxGB       =   ds.?
  FROM  sys.databases d
        JOIN sys.database_service_objectives sdo ON d.database_id = sdo.database_id
        JOIN ? ds                                ON d.database_id = ds.database_id
 WHERE  d.name != N'master'
 ORDER  BY d.name;
```

However, I have not been able to find a DMV to use for "ds". Can you help?

Comment: does this help ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs#calculating-database-and-objects-sizes

Comment: @KinShah Sadly no, sys.database_files only works within one database. It doesn't even have a column for database_id or database_name. It doesn't come up with the correct number for MAXSIZE anyway, I think it calculates the maximum allocated space.